# Could I use "normal" headphones with an electronic drum?

Tags: drums, headphones, electronic-drumset

I have recently purchased a [Roland TD-4KP](https://www.roland.com/global/products/v-drums_portable_td-4kp/) drum kit (that did not arrive yet), and I am wondering if it is possible to use my current headphone (a [Sony WH-1000XM2](https://www.sony.com/electronics/headband-headphones/wh-1000xm2)) to play the drum, or is it required for me to have a **monitor headphone**?

The point here is that I don't want to invest in a monitor headphone right now, as I am just starting with the drums. I do plan to acquire the right headphone later. And, I know that the Sony headphone may work with the drum, but I am not sure if its audio settings will reproduce the drums sound with some reliable confidence.

P.S: I know that if I go to use my current headphone, I must use the cable (not Bluetooth).

Comment: Monitor headphones and regular headphones are the same things. Generally, if something uses the same cable and has the same function it can be used interchangeably. (Except when playing with anything with high voltages like guitar amps, the output of the amplifier section cannot be plugged into a low voltage device or it will be fried)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your normal headphones will work fine. When somebody says "monitor headphones" or "monitor speakers", it typically just means that they're calibrated for accuracy—the kind of accuracy you'd want for mixing music rather than just listening to it. Consumer-grade gear, on the other hand, tends to hype the bass and sometimes the treble a little bit. But any headphones you have will be good enough to hear yourself play.

Comment: Monitor headphones focus on two areas - studio recording, as you mentioned, and live playing. Some also try to cover both areas but these two situations are quite different in practice.